# xsl:for-each in table columns

Tags: xml, xslt, html-table

I've just started learning XML/XSL and I've hit a roadblock in one of my assignments. Tried Googling and searching over here but I can't seem to find a question that has a solution that is basic. So what I'm trying to do is to display the weather nodes in columns instead of rows. No matter how I try to edit my tr or td, the output is always a single column. Not sure where I've gone wrong...

**Desired Output**:
[Picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MpO3Z.jpg)

**XML**

```
<weather>
 <year>2019</year>  
 <month>2</month>
 <date>23</date>
 <dayOfWeek>THU</dayOfWeek> 
 <forecast>Plenty of sunshine</forecast>
 <overallCode>sunny</overallCode>
 <hightemperature scale="">25</hightemperature>
 <lowtemperature scale="">11</lowtemperature>
</weather>

<weather>
 <year>2019</year>  
 <month>2</month>
 <date>24</date>
 <dayOfWeek>WED</dayOfWeek> 
 <forecast>Partly sunny</forecast>
 <overallCode>partlySunny</overallCode> 
 <hightemperature scale="">21</hightemperature>
 <lowtemperature scale="">10</lowtemperature>
</weather>

<weather>
 <year>2019</year>  
 <month>2</month>
 <date>25</date>
 <dayOfWeek>TUE</dayOfWeek> 
 <forecast>A morning shower, then rain</forecast>
 <overallCode>rain</overallCode>
 <hightemperature scale="">19</hightemperature>
 <lowtemperature scale="">10</lowtemperature>
</weather>
```

**XSL**

```
<table border="1">

<xsl:for-each select="weather">
<xsl:sort select="date"/>

<tr>
<td>
            <font color="blue">
                <xsl:value-of select="dayOfWeek" /> 
            </font>
                <xsl:text>  </xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="month" />
                <xsl:text>/</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="date" />
</td>
</tr>                   


<tr>
<td>                
    <img>
        <xsl:attribute name="src">
        <xsl:text>images/</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="overallCode"/>
        <xsl:text>.png</xsl:text>
        </xsl:attribute>

        <xsl:attribute name="width">
        <xsl:text>60px</xsl:text>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </img>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
    <font size="6"><b><xsl:value-of select="hightemperature" />
    <xsl:text>&#176;</xsl:text></b></font>
    <xsl:text>/</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="lowtemperature" />
    <xsl:text>&#176;</xsl:text>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><xsl:value-of select="forecast" /></td>
</tr>


</xsl:for-each>
</table>
```

Please pardon me if my code makes you laugh/angry, I'm still learning!

Comment: Please post a [mcve] next time, not snippets.

Comment: P.S. If `2019-02-24` is a Wednesday (which it isn't), then `2019-02-23` must be Tuesday and `2019-02-25` must be Thursday - not the other way around. Also, if you need to sort them, don't sort by day only otherwise you'll get a surprise at month boundary.

Comment: Thanks Michael and duly noted on the MCVE portion, will do so in the future. I was so busy trying to figure out what went wrong in my XSL that I didn't notice the date/day mismatches! Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: If you look at your code, you'll see that it only outputs one `td` within each `tr`, so it's obvious why it only produces one column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to pivot your table, you must create the rows manually, and use `xsl:for-each` to create the cells in each row.

Example:

**XML**

```
<forecast>
  <weather>
    <year>2019</year>
    <month>2</month>
    <date>23</date>
    <dayOfWeek>THU</dayOfWeek>
    <forecast>Plenty of sunshine</forecast>
    <overallCode>sunny</overallCode>
    <hightemperature scale="">25</hightemperature>
    <lowtemperature scale="">11</lowtemperature>
  </weather>
  <weather>
    <year>2019</year>
    <month>2</month>
    <date>24</date>
    <dayOfWeek>WED</dayOfWeek>
    <forecast>Partly sunny</forecast>
    <overallCode>partlySunny</overallCode>
    <hightemperature scale="">21</hightemperature>
    <lowtemperature scale="">10</lowtemperature>
  </weather>
  <weather>
    <year>2019</year>
    <month>2</month>
    <date>25</date>
    <dayOfWeek>TUE</dayOfWeek>
    <forecast>A morning shower, then rain</forecast>
    <overallCode>rain</overallCode>
    <hightemperature scale="">19</hightemperature>
    <lowtemperature scale="">10</lowtemperature>
  </weather>
</forecast>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/forecast">
    <xsl:variable name="col" select="weather"/>
    <table border="1" >
        <!-- DATE -->
        <tr>
            <xsl:for-each select="$col">
                <td>
                    <font color="blue">
                        <xsl:value-of select="dayOfWeek" /> 
                    </font>
                    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="month" />
                    <xsl:text>/</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="date" />
                </td>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </tr>
        <!-- IMG -->
        <tr>
            <xsl:for-each select="$col">
                <td>
                    <img src="images/{overallCode}.png" width="60px"/>
                </td>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </tr>
        <!-- HIGH/LOW -->
        <tr>
            <xsl:for-each select="$col">
                <td>
                    <font size="6">
                        <b>
                            <xsl:value-of select="hightemperature" />
                            <xsl:text>&#176;</xsl:text>
                        </b>
                    </font>
                    <xsl:text>/</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="lowtemperature" />
                    <xsl:text>&#176;</xsl:text>
                </td>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </tr>
        <!-- FORECAST -->
        <tr>
            <xsl:for-each select="$col">
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="forecast" />
                </td>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </tr>
    </table>
</xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td><font color="blue">THU</font> 2/23</td>
    <td><font color="blue">WED</font> 2/24</td>
    <td><font color="blue">TUE</font> 2/25</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="images/sunny.png" width="60px"/>
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src="images/partlySunny.png" width="60px"/>
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src="images/rain.png" width="60px"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><font size="6"><b>25°</b></font>/11°</td>
    <td><font size="6"><b>21°</b></font>/10°</td>
    <td><font size="6"><b>19°</b></font>/10°</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Plenty of sunshine</td>
    <td>Partly sunny</td>
    <td>A morning shower, then rain</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

P.S. Consider using in-line CSS instead of style elements.

Comment: It works! Thank you so much! Do you mean using an internal CSS stylesheet?

Comment: I meant inline style, but you could use an internal (or an external) stylesheet just as well: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp

Answer (score 0):

Transposition has been for long time a good use case for [modes](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#modes).

This input

```
<root>
  <weather>
    <year>2019</year>
    <month>2</month>
    <date>23</date>
    <dayOfWeek>THU</dayOfWeek>
    <forecast>Plenty of sunshine</forecast>
    <overallCode>sunny</overallCode>
    <hightemperature scale="">25</hightemperature>
    <lowtemperature scale="">11</lowtemperature>
  </weather>
  <weather>
    <year>2019</year>
    <month>2</month>
    <date>24</date>
    <dayOfWeek>WED</dayOfWeek>
    <forecast>Partly sunny</forecast>
    <overallCode>partlySunny</overallCode>
    <hightemperature scale="">21</hightemperature>
    <lowtemperature scale="">10</lowtemperature>
  </weather>
  <weather>
    <year>2019</year>
    <month>2</month>
    <date>25</date>
    <dayOfWeek>TUE</dayOfWeek>
    <forecast>A morning shower, then rain</forecast>
    <overallCode>rain</overallCode>
    <hightemperature scale="">19</hightemperature>
    <lowtemperature scale="">10</lowtemperature>
  </weather>
</root>
```

And this transformation

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" />
    <xsl:key name="kByName" match="weather/*" use="name()" />
    <xsl:template match="text()|weather[position()!=1]" />
    <xsl:template match="root">
        <table>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </table>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="dayOfWeek|overallCode|hightemperature|forecast">
        <tr>
            <xsl:apply-templates
                select="key('kByName',name())" mode="cell" />
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="dayOfWeek" mode="cell">
        <td>
            <font color="blue">
                <xsl:value-of select="." />
            </font>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(' ',../month,'/',../date)" />
        </td>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="overallCode" mode="cell">
        <td>
            <img src="images/{.}.png" width="60px" />
        </td>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="hightemperature" mode="cell">
        <td>
            <font size="6">
                <b>
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat(.,'&#176;')" />
                </b>
            </font>
            <xsl:value-of
                select="concat('/',../lowtemperature,'&#176;')" />
        </td>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="forecast" mode="cell">
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </td>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Results

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <font color="blue">THU</font> 2/23</td>
      <td>
         <font color="blue">WED</font> 2/24</td>
      <td>
         <font color="blue">TUE</font> 2/25</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Plenty of sunshine</td>
      <td>Partly sunny</td>
      <td>A morning shower, then rain</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <img src="images/sunny.png" width="60px"/>
      </td>
      <td>
         <img src="images/partlySunny.png" width="60px"/>
      </td>
      <td>
         <img src="images/rain.png" width="60px"/>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <font size="6">
            <b>25°</b>
         </font>/11°</td>
      <td>
         <font size="6">
            <b>21°</b>
         </font>/10°</td>
      <td>
         <font size="6">
            <b>19°</b>
         </font>/10°</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I have not used/learnt transposition and modes in my HTML classes yet and there some words in the code above that seems alien to me but i'll definitely be reading up on these. Thank you for your suggestion!